# jQuery dynamic background-color change is forcing "inline" style on elements that contain the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sup dudes,

So... here's a weird prob.  The goal is to dynamically set the **background-color** of a class, using a color picker, where certain "div" element(s) may or may not contain that class.

The following code "kind of" works, however, elements that contain the class, (where the background-color is being changed), is for some reason changing the background-color via "inline-style".  (Which makes the whole thing not work)  I've tried !important and a few other things with little success.  Any ideas?

**Note:** .secondaryB is the class with the problem.

```
$('#colorSelector4').ColorPicker({

    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector4 div').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
        $('.secondaryColor').css('color', '#' + hex);
        $('.secondaryColorB').css('background-color', '');
        $('.secondaryColorB').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
    }

});
```

**Note:** Here's what is happening in the Chrome console to elements that contain ".secondaryB".

[image]

Comment: Uhm, that's what javascript does, it applies ***inline styles***, and does not support `!important` at all.

Comment: for what I know you should have a class with those directives already setup to use. Otherwise it will work inline with the .css() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are applying styles directly to elements, you are using the `style` property on those elements and this can only translate into inline styles. There *are* ways of dynamically creating stylesheets however, as [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information).

Given a reference to a stylesheet (e.g. from the `document.styleSheets` array), and a reference to the specific rule you want to change (via the `stylesheet.cssRules` array), you can set its `style` property and it will modify the stylesheet itself, instead of the inline styles. Example:

```
// Assuming that the rule you want is the first rule of the first stylesheet of the page
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

Comment: You are correct my friend, and so was  **adeneo**.  That is exactly how javascript works.  (by modifying the "inline-style", and not the selector class).  Which left me changing the architecture of the front-end.  (Too much to explain what I did, but worked!)